# Block current thread till part of code ran on main thread in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

*I have a use case where i am writing data to local couchebase database in ios. Here it will not support concurrent access of write operation. So i want to run the CRUD operation on main thread and return result after running some algorithm on data on secondary threads. when main thread took over control and executes code, current running thread is not waiting till main thread completes its operation. How can i  handover result from main thread to other thread.*

Ex :

```
+(BOOL)createDocument:(NSDictionary*)data withId:(NSString*)docId {
    __block CBLDocument* doc = nil;
    //        NSLog(@"%d count ", [[self database] documentCount]);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if(docId.length > 0) {
            doc = [[self getDatabase] documentWithID:docId];
        } else {
            doc = [[self getDatabase] createDocument];
        }
    });

    //I want current thread to wait till main thread completes its execution
    if(doc){
        return YES;
    }else{
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know for a fact that this method is not called from the main queue, you can use `dispatch_sync`:

```
+(BOOL)createDocument:(NSDictionary*)data withId:(NSString*)docId {
    __block CBLDocument* doc = nil;

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if(docId.length > 0) {
            doc = [[self getDatabase] documentWithID:docId];
        } else {
            doc = [[self getDatabase] createDocument];
        }
    });

    //I want current thread to wait till main thread completes its execution
    if(doc){
        return YES;
    }else{
        return NO;
    }
}
```

---

A more generalized approach would be to create a dedicated, custom dispatch queue for your database interaction. Then, any thread (either the main thread or any background thread) that wants to interact with the database would perform a `dispatch_sync` to that dedicated queue.

This provides a cleaner implementation, making the functional intent more explicit, and ensures that database interaction initiated from a background thread will not block the main thread (unless, of course, the main thread happens to be initiating database interactions with this database queue at the same time). This dedicated queue approach is in the spirit of the "One Queue per Subsystem" design pattern discussed in [WWDC 2012 video, Asynchronous Design Patterns with Blocks, GCD, and XPC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=712) (it's the fifth design pattern discussed in the latter part of the video).

Answer (score 0):

You can make another `dispatch_async` call to your "current thread" from the main thread. So you'll use another function block and put your `if(doc)` stuff into that. That's how chaining between threads are handled with GCD API.

So the problem with your code is, `createDocument` returning after dispatching to another thread. Instead, you should change `createDocument` to take a function block argument.

```
+(BOOL)createDocument:(NSDictionary*)data 
  withId:(NSString*)docId 
  onComplete:(void (^)(CBLDocument*))onComplete;
```

And change your `dispatch_async` call as follows:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if(docId.length > 0) {
        doc = [[self getDatabase] documentWithID:docId];
    } else {
        doc = [[self getDatabase] createDocument];
    }
    dispatch_async(yourCurrentThread, ^{
        onComplete(doc);
    });
});
```

However if you really want to BLOCK your current thread, you should use `dispatch_sync` instead of `dispatch_async`.

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    ...
});

return doc != nil;
```

Sorry if there are any syntax errors, I haven't tested this.